# How can i read xml item's attribute?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm newbie in Sencha touch and i need to parse a xml file.
I can display data between tag but i can't display data when i have an attribute.

some body can help me please.Thanks for advance

Comment: excuse me.I will accept answers on my previous questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapping property in your field definition.

```
Ext.define('temp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'pseudo', type: 'string', mapping: '@pseudo' },
            { name: 'id',     type: 'int' },
            { name: 'name',   type: 'string' },
        ]       
    }
});
```

Will read this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
  <user pseudo="pierre">
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Pierre</name>
  </user>
  <user pseudo="zorg">
    <id>99</id>
    <name>Zorglub</name>
  </user>
</users>
```

I know this is an old post, but since I found the question when searching for the answer...